# Make the language of notifications match the language of the site they correspond to

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, languages, internationalization

I participate in both the [English Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/) and the [Russian Stack Overflow site](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). When I look at my notifications, the language of the notification corresponds to the language of the site I am currently on.

At first glance, this seems like exactly what you should expect, but this behavior confuses me fairly often. For example, recently I got this notification,

[image]

which made me think, "Stack Overflow in Russian is graduating and having moderator elections already? Awesome!"

Actually, it was for the main Stack Overflow moderator elections. This is what the notification looks like when viewed from an English-language site:

[image]

In a similar way, I'm often confused when I earn a badge on Stack Overflow in English, but see the notification *in Russian* while I'm using Stack Overflow in Russian. It always disappoints me a little bit when this happens, since earning badges on the Russian site is still a new and exciting thing for me, whereas earning badges on the English site is a relatively mundane occurrence.

I should note that it is possible to distinguish which site is being referred to, since the icons for Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow in Russian are different, (compare [image: Stack Overflow logo] and [image: Stack Overflow на русском logo]) but for me this is a much weaker cue than the language of the message.

Can we make it so that notifications for Stack Overflow in Russian are always in Russian and notifications for Stack Overflow in English are always in English, no matter which site site I happen to be using at the time? In general, can we make the language of notifications match the language of the site they correspond to?

Comment: I also got confused by this when an English related notification popped up when I'm on [pt.so].

Answer (score 3):

This is marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), however, the system supporting it is still kind of fragile. If you see English out of place in these, it's likely a bug in Transifex integration (or a system-generated string that has yet to be translated), and it should be reported.

Note, this *only* applies to strings that the system sends as messages, if you get an @comment reply, we display that however it was written.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) should be marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as nowadays the notitifications on localized Stack Overflow sites are shown in the corresponding languages, at least this is occurs on [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com.)